# Makefile - How to run concurrently clients after server?

Tags: c, linux, shell, makefile

Currently, I do a client - server program with IPC via shared memory, and I have a little problem when run this with make, I want run server and run simultaneously 3 clients in a only one make target and doesn't work but with 2 targets it works. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Here the code that works for me:

```
OPT_GCC = -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra
#compiler options and libraries for Linux
OPT = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700
LIB = -lrt -lpthread

CLIENTS = 3
MFLAGS = -j$(CLIENTS)

all: client server

client: mediasharingclient.c
    gcc $(OPT_GCC) $(OPT) -o client mediasharingclient.c $(LIB)

server: mediasharingserver.c
    gcc $(OPT_GCC) $(OPT) -o server mediasharingserver.c $(LIB)

run_server: server
   ./server ../sample1/send-order.txt&

run_clients: client1 client2 client3

client1:
    ./client 1 client1

client2:
    ./client 2 client2

client3:
    ./client 3 client3

clean:
   rm -f client server
```

I do: `make run_server` and `make run_clients -j3`

Comment: This works for me using GNU Make 4.1. When you say that it works with 2 targets, do you mean that it works with 2 clients (client1 and client2), or with server and one client?

Comment: I want to tell you that I make 2 times (one for the server and one for clients) Before it has `run: run_server run_c1 run_c2 run_c3` and run `make run -j4` but this does not work properly because the server does not always executed before that clients process

Comment: But are you able to run 2 clients in parallel? What OS are you running and what brand of make? I don't think the problem is in the Makefile.

Comment: I have GNU Make 4.0, The problem is not the make, the works well, but the way I'm running does not give me the expected flow is a problem of logic and no programming in the makefile.

Comment: Are you sure that Make doesn't run all 3 clients? Maybe it runs all of them but not all of them can connect to the server?

Comment: Yes , It do, but I want only one make instruction instead of two and that if I have problems when I want to run in parallel clients after running the server, I want it on a single target, is this possible?

Comment: Oh, now I understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work without changing the client or server implementation, we will have to assume that the server will be ready within a fixed time, say 2 seconds:

```
OPT_GCC = -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra
#compiler options and libraries for Linux
OPT = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700
LIB = -lrt -lpthread

all: client server

client: mediasharingclient.c
    gcc $(OPT_GCC) $(OPT) -o client mediasharingclient.c $(LIB)

server: mediasharingserver.c
    gcc $(OPT_GCC) $(OPT) -o server mediasharingserver.c $(LIB)

run_server: server
    ./server ../sample1/send-order.txt &
    sleep 2

run_clients: client1 client2 client3

client1: client run_server
    ./client 1 client1

client2: client run_server
    ./client 2 client2

client3: client run_server
    ./client 3 client3

clean:
    rm -f client server
```

and run it with `make -j run_clients`. The dependency on `run_server` for each client makes sure that the client targets are not run in parallel with the `run_server` target while it is sleeping and starting the server.

Other options are to have the clients try repeatedly for a few seconds, or have the server fork to the background and terminate when it is ready to accept connections (and then don't run it in the background from the Makefile).